# C: create an array of array with memcpy

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create and fill an array of array. This is the code I've written:

```
int b[4] = {100, 100, 200, 300};
int a[2][4];

int main(){
    memcpy(a[0], b, sizeof(int));
    printf("%i", a[0][2]);
```

I shoulde get *200*, but instead I get *0*...how can I solve it?

Comment: Why `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: To make sure that there would be space enough (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only copying one int from b.  You need to copy all of b to a[0] like this

```
int b[4] = {100, 100, 200, 300};
int a[2][4];

int main(){
    memcpy(a[0], b, sizeof(b));
    printf("%i", a[0][2]);
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! The problem was that I thought sizeof(int) returned the maximum size of an integer, and not the size of a single one.

Comment: what "the maximum size of an integer" is and how could that make the code work is beyond me.

Comment: @Matteo Secco: What's the implied difference between "maximum size of an integer" and "size of a single one"?

Answer (score 2):

Should it be the correct b array size?

```
memcpy(a[0], b, sizeof(int) * 4);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! The problem was that I thought sizeof(int) returned the maximum size of an integer, and not the size of a single one.

Comment: `sizeof b` would be better.

Comment: @MatteoSecco The maximum size of an integer is the same as the size of a single integer. What does either of them have to do with the size of an array of 4 integers?

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**

`memcpy(a[0], b, sizeof(int));`

**with**

`memcpy(a[0], b, sizeof(b));`

**Reason**

You were only copying 1 integer i.e. the first element from b by specifying size of 1 integer. But if you need to copy all elements from b, you need to specify size of all elements together or simply size of b.